# Animated GIFs in Lotus Notes

Tags: animated-gif

I have built a HTML email newsletter containing an animated GIF Christmas Ecard which is being sent to all employees of a company who exclusively use Lotus Notes.

The problem I'm having is that they are receiving the email fine, but the GIF isn't animating.

Any idea if there's a way to get this working?

Comment: Any company that uses Lotus Notes does not deserve xmas cards

Comment: Hey, don't blame everyone for decisions made by a few zealots.

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure that the first frame of the gif looks nice so that the animation is an 'added benefit' rather than a requirement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately they require that it be animated, and that last year they had an animated gif come through working.

Answer (score 0):

That they had one come through last year seems amazing to me. But if that is actually the truth it might have had something to do with the file size being too large. You should try to keep them under 40kb

Answer (score 0):

Click `Create` in the toolbar above the email message. Click on the `Picture` option and then choose `GIF` from the pull-down menu. Go to the folder location of the animated GIF that you want to embed in the email. Click and highlight the file. Click the `Import` button to add the animated GIF.